# Best way to get a comma delineated string into xml format?

Tags: xml, .net-2.0, datatable

Using VB.net (.net 2.0)
I have a string in this format:

```
record1_field1,record1_field2,record2_field3,record2_field1,record2_field2,
```

etc...

I wonder what the best (easiest) way is to get this into an xml?

I can think of 2 ways:

Method 1:
- use split to get the items in an array
- loop through array and build an xml string using concatenation

Method 2:
- use split to get the items in an array
- loops through array to build a datatable
- use writexml to output xml from the datatable

The first sounds pretty simple but would require more logic to build the string.

The second seems slicker and easier to understand.

Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: How do you know where record1 ends and record two begings?  Will there always be three fields or are there line breaks that we can't see?

Comment: And do you care if the fields are treated as elements or attributes?

Comment: There will always be a set number of fields per each record so we can tell where one record ends and another begins.

There is no hard requirement on whether a field should be an element or attribute, however I plan to make them elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocuent();

string[] data = csv.split(',');

XmlNode = doc.CreateElement("root");
foreach(string str in data)
{
    XmlNode node = doc.CreateElement("data");
    node.innerText = str;
    root.AppendChild(node);
}
Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerXML);
```

Should return something like this:

```
<root>
    <data>field 1</data>
    <data>field 2</data>
    <data>field 3</data>
</root>
```

You would have to nest loops / tokenize a bit differently for nested data...

Comment: look at his sample more carefully: there's some nesting going on there this won't account for.

Comment: I chose this as answer because it gives me a good idea of how to start.  Joe's answer also helped, but this one is more complete.  And thanks to Joel for pointing out additional things to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing string concatenation, you could probably create an XmlDocument and stuff it with the appropriate XmlElement and XmlAttribute objects from your string...  Then, write out the XmlDocument object...